# Как отслеживать обновления на Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Как отслеживать обновления на Stack Overflow?

- Есть ли возможность отслеживать новые вопросы на сайте?
- Какие варианты отслеживания доступы участникам?

Answer (score 14):

### Подписка по почте

Для то, чтобы изменить вашу подписку на почтовые уведомления:

1. Перейдите на страницу вашей учётной записи. Для этого, нажмите на изображение в верхней части экрана.

[image: Учётная запись пользователя в верхней части экрана]

2. Перейдите на вкладку «Править». Для этого, нажмите на надпись «Править», в верхнем разделе меню, под основными кнопками.

[image: Перейти в раздел править]

3. Перейдите в раздел «Параметры».

[image: Перейти в раздел параметры]

4. Настройте почтовые уведомления об основных событиях на сайте (вопросах, ответах, упоминание в чате, наградах, новых достижениях и т. д.). Робот будет оправлять на указанную почту письма с заданным периодом (раз в три часа, раз в сутки или раз в неделю).

[image: Настройка основной подписки]

Вы можете более детально управлять подпиской [с помощью фильтров](http://stackexchange.com/filters/8721/my-filter), которые позволяют получать уведомления каждые 15 минут. Для этого, перейдите по ссылке «Управление подпиской на вопросы по фильтру».

[image: Страница настройки фильтров]

5. Настройте подписку на еженедельные новости с лучшими вопросами и ответами.

[image: Новостная рассылка]

Вы можете более детально настроить новостную подписку на [специальной странице подписок в вашей сетевой учётной записи](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions), перейдя по ссылке «Управление подписками новостных рассылок».

### RSS–лента

Для отслеживания обновлений, вы можете использовать RSS–ленту.

1. Для подписки на новые вопросы, перейдите в самый низ главной страницы сайта.

[image: Подписка, главная]

2. Для подписки на вопросы по выбранной метке или комбинации меток, сделайте выборку вопросов и перейдите вниз страницы.

   Для этого, перейдите в раздел «Метки».

[image: Метки]

Кликните на метку, вопросы по которой хотите отслеживать.

[image: Метка C#]

Если вы хотите сделать выборку по нескольким меткам, в боковой панели кликните на связанную метку.

[image: Связанные метки]

Перейдите вниз страницы

[image: Подписка по C# и ASP.NET]

3. Для подписки на обновления выбранного вопроса, перейдите в самый низ выбранного вопроса.

[image: Подписка на вопрос]

## В завершение

Большинство событий связанных с сайтом вопросов и ответов и чатом будут отображаться во «входящих сообщениях», ссылка на которые находится в верхней части сайта.

[image: Входящие]

Comment: Могу заметить, что в RSS-ленте отдаётся только 30 постов. Поэтому чем больше тегов засунуто в одну ленту, тем выше шанс что-то пропустить. Эффективней для каждого тега создавать свою ленту.

Comment: @PinkTux Достаточно настроить клиент, чтобы он запрашивал обновления достаточно часто.Десять запросов в день — и хоть нефильтрованную ленту в клиент засовывай.